# Is there a way to permanently preserve the functions of the spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript

I made a sheet for writing proposals using the functions of Google Spreadsheet.

When all proposals are made, further modifications must be made manually.

Is there a way to save the current state and restore it by clicking the button even if someone else modifies it?

Comment: You have probably tagged this question incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

`cmd + option (alt) + shift + H` will bring up the version history of a sheet.